# IE11 cross domain cache with XHR

Tags: https, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

I'm having this problem only in IE11. Chrome and Firefox both work fine.

I'm trying to get an image from a different domain using XHR. The image is hosted in an https address. The code is similar to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajojw9cq/

```
<img src="https://wordmagicbox.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/moto-morini-scrambler.jpeg?w=300&h=208" width=200 height=200/>

<script>

    function handleStateChange() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            switch (xhr.status) {

            case 200:
                console.log("200");
                break;

            case 404:
                handleError();
                break;

            case 304:
                console.log("304");
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://img.desmotivaciones.es/201104/Sinttulo_2159.jpg");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
    xhr.send(null);

</script>
```

The main difference between this fiddle and my code are the links and that I know that the image's domain actually allows my domain to get images from it.

I do get the images on every browser, but IE11 doesn't seem to cache them, even with `xhr.msCaching = "enabled"`.

IE11 is also sending a "`Cache-control: no-cache`" header in every one of these XHR requests, which is strange. I've tried to overwrite that header, but it didn't seem to work.

Another observation is that when I use an `<img>` tag and set the `src` to be that image's url, it caches normally and I get a 304. If I use XHR or the `Image()` class, it doesn't cache (200), and I really need it to cache one of these two.

Is this an IE11 bug/issue? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add "http://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/" to the beginning of the URL.

Comment: The server where I'm getting the image from already appends "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to the response.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be a documented limitation and only supported under Microsoft Edge

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673569(v=vs.85).aspx

> Microsoft Edge improves networking performance by caching resources downloaded via CORS-enabled XHR operations in the same manner as it would if they had been downloaded directly. Previously, under many circumstances, caching would be disabled for such items. This new behavior allows more resources to be loaded from the local disk on subsequent requests, reducing network use and improving load times."

Workaround is to add the site in the trusted zone and change security setting to activate cross domain data source, but I think its only viable for limited case like intranet or special app and not for public facing web site

Another workaround may be to persist the resource in the local storage